# Filter logic like in reports

Tags: javascript, python, filter, logic

This kind of filter logic :  `(1 and 2) or 3`
can be implemented in Python or Javascript, any ideas? I didnt found nothing google.
I mean ,  user will type filter in textarea, need to check filter's grammar (mb with regex) and parse filter.
Example of valid and invalid filters:

```
1 or 2 : valid
(1 and 3) or 2 : valid
(1 or 2 and ) 3 : invalid
1 and 2 (or 3) : valid
1 (2 and 3) : invalid
```

any ideas how to do this?

Comment: I'd just like to point out how incredibly unwise it is to evaluate text entered by a user as a Python command.

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, since boolean expressions can have multiple nested levels - this is not a regular language, and thus it wouldn't be possible to create a regex for that without imposing some constraints on the input.

In python, I would use `eval` to achieve this. If the syntax is incorrect an exception would be thrown. As mentioned in comments, take into consideration that this is risky security-wise, so I would check the input text first to avoid injection. See some examples:

```
In [11]: eval('1 or 2')
Out[11]: 1

In [12]: eval('1 (2 and 3)')
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-12-96e407050456> in <module>()
----> 1 eval('1 (2 and 3)')

<string> in <module>()

TypeError: 'int' object is not callable

In [13]: eval('1 and 2 (or 3)')
  File "<string>", line 1
    1 and 2 (or 3)
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax


In [14]: eval('(1 and 3) or 2')
Out[14]: 3
```